# Using System.Drawing.Printing to get Queue Status

Tags: c#, printing, system.drawing, system.management

I've been trying to use `System.Drawing.Printing;` in order to get the queue status of a network printer.

I can retrieve the properties of the printer but I can't really seem to get the queue status.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
ps.PrinterName = "ES5461 MFP(PCL)"; // Load the appropriate printer's setting
```

From there I can see that the Printer is valid since `ps.IsValid` is `true` but I can't go any further.

I've tried as well to use `System.Management` to retrieve the status but I just know how to dump the information and there's no queue information as well.

```
string printerName = "ES5461";
string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%'", printerName);

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
{
    foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value));
    }
}
```

Do you know of any way to retrieve the queue status (number of documents) using any .dll?

Comment: As from .NET 3.0 you can use the PrintQueue class. have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.getjob(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I already lookep that up but it is not recomended by Microsoft to use it in any ASP.Net services: "Classes within the System.Printing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions." Thank you anyway.

Comment: According to microsoft, the System.Drawing.Printing namespace is to be used for winforms as well.

Comment: @MiquelColl - why do you pay attention to that warning about `System.Printing` but ignore the similar warning for [`System.Drawing.Printing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Oops. I didn't see that one. My fault. Sorry; Either way I'm trying to use what Nissim said again and it seems I'm getting to something. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Nissim I could solve it:

```
var printServer = new PrintServer();
var myPrintQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

foreach (PrintQueue pq in myPrintQueues)
{
    pq.Refresh();
    if (!pq.Name.ToLower().Contains("es5461")) continue;  
    PrintJobInfoCollection jobs = pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();
    foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo job in jobs)
    {
        var aux = job;
    }// end for each print job    
}// end for each print queue
```

As you can see using the `PrintServer` (`System.Printing`) combined with the `PrintQueue` as suggested by Nissim I can actually access to the queue information.

Comment: I was just reading through this as I am working on a web service that does network printing, `PrintServer` is not in `System.Drawing.Printing` it is in `System.Printing`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @RyanWilson. Indeed the correct reference is in there.

Comment: Thank you for updating that. I just didn't want to see a good answer displaying incorrect info. Good post though. +1 from me.